# Docker run -v mounting a file as a directory

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I'm trying to mount a directory containing a file some credentials onto a container with the -v flag, but instead of mounting that file as a file, it mounts it as a directory:

Run script:

```
$ mkdir creds/
$ cp key.json creds/key.json
$ ls -l creds/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2340 Oct 12 22:59 key.json
$ docker run -v /*pathToWorkingDirectory*/creds:/creds *myContainer* *myScript*
```

When I look at the debug spew of the `docker run` command, I see that it creates the `/creds/` directory, but for some reason creates `key.json` as a subdirectory under that, rather than copying the file.

I've seen some other posts saying that if you tell `docker run` to mount a file it can't find, it will create a directory on the container with the filename, but since I didn't specify the filename and it knew to name the new directory 'key.json' it seems like it was able to find the file, but created it as a directory anyway? Has anyone run into this before?

In case it's relevant, the script is being run in Docker-in-Docker in another container as part of GitLab's CI process.

Comment: What's your platform? And what's the docker version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running Docker-in-Docker, this means when you specify a `-v` volume, Docker will look for this directory on the **host** since the shared sock enabling Docker-in-Docker actualy means your run command starts a container alongside the runner container.

I explain this in more detail in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441426/2078207):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441426/2078207

Also notice the comment below this answer to get a direction for a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I wasn't able to get it working quite like that, but it's good to know. I eventually managed to solve it by passing in the credential string via --build-args instead.